# How to do Background Image horizontal slide

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

In a mobile web application i want to create a home page where the background image has got an animation like a portrait image slide.

Eg: mobile has got a screen with 360px .. i have a background image 500px ..On page load show position 0 t0 300 and then slide automatically until 600px.

Got this idea from pegasus airlines mobile app.

Can any body guide how to implement using CSS,HTML,JQUERY.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After putting everything in place, you need to use jQuery animate() function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $("#mycontainerID").animate({"background-position": "-300px"}, 2000,'linear'); });
```

Supposing that your background is located in 0,0 and you want the animation to lasts 2s.